# TypeScript with Options API (Nuxt.js) and Number Input Fields

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm new to TypeScript in Nuxt.js and currently trying to implement a very simple form with two input types (string and text). However, since I'm using the data object for properties with v-model, I can't figure out how to best handle the number input field (phone number in this case). For strings it's no problem obviously, because setting the property to "" already is an empty string. But I didn't find anything on how to set an object to an "empty number".

I suppose I'm just following an incorrect approach altogether with this. Here's the code:

```html
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <input type="text" v-model="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" v-model="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="number" v-model.number="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <button type="submit">Submit Data</button>
  </form>

interface dataProperties {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  phone: number
}

export default defineComponent({
  data(): dataProperties {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use union types. It allows you to define a variable as a string, or a number, or an array, or an object, etc,...

We can create union types by using the pipe symbol (|) between each type.

```
e.g: let yourVar: string | number
```

In your case, you can use " number | null ". It means the phone can be a number or null.

```
interface dataProperties {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  phone: number|null
}
```